# Nested JSON to backbone model

Tags: backbone.js, collections, model

I'm quite new to backbone.js and currently struggling with structuring the data properly.
I have JSON that I need to map to the backbone model/collection.

What's the best way to approach this kind of nested data?
resultSet should be a collection of "result" models but how do I include other data like "resultURL", "clearKeywordUrl" etc. ?

```
"resultUrl":"",
"clearKeywordUrl":"",
"resultTotal": 10,
"nextPageUrl" : ""
"resultSet":[
{
    "id":"",
    "title":"",
    "subTitle":null,
    "summary":""
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

If i get it right you want the content of resultSet to be your collections models, and the other keys are some kind of "meta" info for your collection? You could override the parse method of your collection to store the metadata in the collection object and use only the content of resultSet as your models: (untested concept proposal)

```
var coll = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  parse: function(data){

   this.resultUrl       = data.resultUrl;
   this.clearKeywordUrl = data.clearKeywordUrl;
   this.nextPageUrl     = data.nextPageUrl;

   return data.resultSet; //use only the resultSet content as models

  },

  initialize: function(options){
   console.log("resultUrl", this.resultUrl);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a **model** with name **Result**
And Result has following attributes:

```
resultUrl: '',
clearKeywordUrl: '',
...
```

And this model has a field called **resultSet** which will be the collection of results. 
And define a separate model with name **resultSetItem** with some defaults.

If you get some time, checkout the introductory video from Thomas Davis at [Backbone Tutorials](http://backbonetutorials.com/)